# Weights and Biases (wandb), Explain metrics displayed in WandB

Tags: wandb

I'm looking for a thorough explanation of all the plots displayed in a basic WandB dashboard, such as:

- train/loss
- train/global_step
- train/train_samples_per_second
- train/train_loss

This is part of my dashboard
[image]

Mainly, I'm looking for practical info, e.g. "a lower train/train_loss is better", to be able to diagnose my model runs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**W&B dashboards will plot any data, so it's impossible to say without context about the model/training loop.**

Users log to W&B using `wandb.log({'some_metric': some_value})` so it can be completely user defined. Some [libraries have integrations](https://docs.wandb.ai/guides/integrations) so they will log their metrics in their own way too.

That said, in your example "train_loss" is a pretty standard metric in machine learning which is the "loss" of your model using the training data. This is computed by your *loss function* which depends on the task you're training. Lower loss is better.

*global_step* is typically every update step of your model.

Because the other charts are bar charts, they're likely just 1 value per run. In your case, the names are pretty self-explanatory:
`train samples per second` - how many samples (data examples) are being given to the model every second.
`train runtime` - how long it took to train
`train steps per second` - how many model update steps happen every second